# Why isn't :last-of-type working on tumblr?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Despite limiting the `:last-of-type` to a certain `div`, when I add another div under that div, the `:last-of-type` class is suddenly canceled. Is there a reason why?

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}

.container:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  <div class="container">
    {block:Posts} ....... {/block:Posts}
  </div>
  <div class="pagination">....</div>
</div>
```

Using this code, if I removed the `.pagination` div, the `:last-of-type` works normally and removes the `border-bottom`.
But if I add the `.pagination` div, suddenly the `:last-of-type` doesn't work even though the `.pagination` div isn't included in the container class.

Is there a way to fix it? Or to select the last div of the `.container` div without having the `.pagination` class affecting it?

Comment: "type" in "last-of-type" refers to the element name (i.e "div"), not the class name or the simple selector.

Comment: You're looking for a `:last-of-class` selector, which doesn't exist.

Comment: You can workaround that behaviour by changing `div.container` into `article.container` or `section.container`. It will be another type of block and should work

Answer (score 0):

You’re selecting `.container`, not the last of its children. The form `.container:last-of-type` selects anything of class `.container` that is the last of its type. By inserting a space, which is the generic descendant selector, or a right angle bracket (>), which is the direct descendant selector, you’re now selecting the last of a given type within any element of class `.container`.

`.container > :last-of-type`

This may not be your best option, though. You should consider whether last-child makes more sense. For example, if you introduce elements of different a types at some point, the last of each type will be selected.

Answer (score 0):

`last-of-type` refers to the *element type* (in this case `div`), not to the class, so it won't work the way you expect it, but will select the `.pagination` DIV, which is the last DIV inside the container element.

However, if the last `.container` div is always the second last DIV in there (only followed by the `.pagination` div, you can use `:nth-last-of-type(2)`:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #111;
}

.container:nth-last-of-type(2) {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="entry">
  <div class="container">
    container content
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    container content
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    container content
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    container content
  </div>
  <div class="pagination">....</div>
</div>
```